# Aviary Editor Loads blank image until screen is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, filepicker.io, aviary

So I have an instance of aviary editor on my site, it pulls images from filepicker and then resubmits them. The problem I am having is that when I load an image, it initially has a thumbnail I have loaded appear, then the screen goes blank...until I resize the screen and the image appears normally.

Here is what it looks like, notice the image dimensions in the bottom. They go from the already loaded thumbnail to a blank image, with the correct dimensions displayed until I slightly change the windows size.

While it is loading, dimensions of the thumbnail in bottom
[image: While it is loading, dimensions of the thumbnail in bottom]
After it has loaded, correct dimensions in bottom
[image: After it has loaded, correct dimensions in bottom]
After slightly changing window dimensions, the image appears
[image: After slightly changing window dimensions, the image appears]

Here is my initialization code:

```
function initEditor( apiKey ){
var tools = ['enhance', 'orientation', 'focus', 'resize', 'crop', 'effects'];
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    apiVersion: 3,
    displayImageSize: true,
    tools: tools,
    maxSize: 800,
    theme: 'minimum',
    onSave: function(image, newUrl){
        //onSave function, sends to external filePicker source 
    },
    onError: function(errorObj){
        console.log(errorObj);
    },
    onLoad: function(){
        //load only if there is an img
        if (typeof img !== 'undefined'){
            openEditor(img, src, featherEditor);
        }
    }
});
return featherEditor;
}
```

Opening Code:

`image = "img-id_image_relations-0-image"`

`src = "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/mX42P6fLRS6YDP58moIH"`

```
function openEditor(image, src, editor){
editor.launch({
    image: image,
    url: src
});
//return false;
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Loading the image into a div before opening,
- Simplifying the feather initialization to the bare minimum,
- Test on external facing server and localhost,

What stinks is when I test it on jsFiddle it works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/TD4Ud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very dirty, but I found a temporary solution of firing the window resize event when the image loads. I would love there to be a better answer, but this will work in the interim.

Add this as the onReady event in the initialization:

```
onReady: function(){
        //this is an abomination but it works
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    }
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, I think the aviary guys need to fix this. Until then will try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: If this doesn't work, set a timeout to dispatch the event. For me, the onReady event was fired before the canvas was ready.